# How to change a value in a parameter in python from parse_qsl?

Tags: python

I need to add +four to the parameter q and unparse the query string after making the modification.  The problem I'm having is parse_qsl gives tuples in a list so I can't modify the tuple. I can't use parse_qs because I have multiple parameters with the same name.  How do I modify q parameter and unparse the query in this scenario?

```
from urllib import parse
url = 'https://www.test.com/search?q=one+two+three&array[]=apple&array[]=oranges'
parts = parse.urlparse(url)
querys = parse.parse_qsl(parts.query)

# >>> querys
# [('q', 'one two three'), ('array[]', 'apple'), ('array[]', 'oranges')]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understood your question correctly, is this what you want?

```
from urllib import parse

url = 'https://www.test.com/search?q=one+two+three&array[]=apple&array[]=oranges'
parts = parse.urlparse(url)
querys = [list(q) for q in parse.parse_qsl(parts.query)]

for q in querys:
    if q[0] == 'q':
        q[1] = q[1] + ' four'

print([tuple(q) for q in querys])
#[('q', 'one two three four'), ('array[]', 'apple'), ('array[]', 'oranges')]
```